# Doubt about the quotient of group $G=\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^2\rangle$ over $H=\langle a,(ab)^3\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, quotient-group

I am a beginner in Group Theory and I have found the following sencence in my Group Theory Lecture notes:

> For another example, take $H$ the subgroup of $G=\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^2\rangle$ generated by $a$ and $(ab)^3$. Then the group $G \backslash H$ has exactly three elements $He, Hb$ and $H(ba)$ [...]

I am trying to understand what really means $G\backslash H$. It can easily show that $H$ is not normal in $G$, so the quotient $G/H$ cannot be constructed. Did $G\backslash H$ means the quotient of $G$ over the normalizer $N_G(H)$ of $H$?

I am not able to construct de normalizer of $H$ in order to check if $G/N_G(H)$ equals $\{He, Hb, H(ba)\}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: $G=\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^2\rangle$ is not free.

Comment: Your $G$ in the title doesn't match that it the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun i fixed it!

Comment: $G\setminus H$ is not standard notation for a quotient. So your Lecture notes have to define what it means.

Comment: If you took the quotient of $G$ by the normal closure of $H$, then in the quotient, $a$ would become the identity, so $(ab)^3 = b^3$.  So, since both $b^2$ and $b^3$ become the identity, so does $b$.  In other words, the quotient of $G$ by the normal closure of $H$ would be the trivial group.

Comment: Looks like it should say "the **set** $G\backslash H$..." (rather than "group"); That is common notation for an arbitrary subgroup: $H/G$ and $G\backslash H$ are the right and left cosets of $H$. (I never remember whish notation goes with which sides; I would expect $H/G$ to be the right cosets and $G\backslash H$ to be the left cosets, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$It seems you are asked to find the distinct right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

First note that $G$ is the [infinite dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group). Writing $c = a b$, [an equivalent presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group#Definition) is
$$
G
=
\Span{c, a : a^{-1} c a = c^{-1}, a^2},
$$
showing that $G$ is a split extension of an infinite cyclic group $\Span{c}$ by a cyclic group $\Span{a}$ of order $2$, with $a$ acting on $\Span{c}$ by inversion.

So $\Span{c^{3}}$ is normal in $G$, and $G / \Span{c^{3}}$ is a dihedral group of order $6$. The rest should be clear.

Comment: Although, since $H$ is not normal in $G$, that raises the question of why the problem is talking about the *group* $G \backslash H$...

Comment: @DanielSchepler, this is a notation I have seen used for the *set* of (right) cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: My point is: if $H$ is not a normal subgroup, then $G \mathop{\backslash} H$ doesn't form a group in any natural way.

Comment: @DanielSchepler, the usual notation for the quotient of a group $G$ with respect to the normal subgroup $N$ is $G/N$.

Comment: I agree with everything you're saying.  But what I'm saying is: the original post includes the words "Then the **group** $G \mathop{\backslash} H$ has exactly three elements..."  My comment is that the word "group" seems misplaced there, if $G \mathop{\backslash} H$ is to be interpreted as the collection of right cosets of $H$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler, my apologies, I hadn't noticed - the word *group* definitely does not belong here.